# Checkers AI game engines

Tags: game-ai, checkers

I have coded an AI checkers game but would like to see how good it is. Some people have informed me to use the Chinook AI opensource code. But I am having trouble trying to integrate that software into my AI code. How do I integrate another game engine in checkers with the AI I have coded?

Comment: Please explain what is preventing you integrating Chinook - e.g. do you get errors, is there a clash of libraries or language support on your machine? Also, it is worth mentioning your project's coding language. Your own code and whatever you integrate with will need to share a game board and be able to inform each other of when they have moved/whether they resign etc.

Comment: I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to integrate it into my code

Comment: Is it just a matter of copying and pasting it?

Comment: I suspect that is unlikely. Are the two projects written in the same language? Do they use the same board representation? Do you have a reference to the Chinook AI code and documentation for its API?

Comment: To put it simply. I have to say no to all of those questions. Can you help me?

Comment: Is there a site whereby it offers a variety of languages for me to choose from so I can just download it?

Comment: No I think it is very unlikely that you will find a conversion to your language if the original does not match. I don't think you have an AI problem here, but are limited by your knowledge/experience of working with third party code or systems. What language is your project in?

Comment: I coded it In C

Comment: OK, so C doesn't come with much help, but it is fast and can connect low-level. Your ideal integration will be with another checkers library written in C, which has at least some documentation. A quick search turned up this: http://www.fierz.ch/checkerboard.php . . . which is a shared checkers "environment" that runs in Windows and that multiple different player engines can share. It may be your best bet - it is unlikely that anyone on AI site can answer questions about integrating it though.

Comment: Final thing that may help - **CheckerBoard** is written so that you can implement your AI as a Windows DLL and copy it into an Engines folder - i.e. all the integration work done for you, including a UI for human-vs-AI play, *provided* you follow the API that it expects of you in your DLL: http://www.fierz.ch/cbdeveloper.php

Comment: @NeilSlater  That is mighty helpful of you Neil, thank you